# Cocoa Pods duplicate symbol error while using framework

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, cocoapods

i am using a framework that uses `AFNetworking` , found that it is stored in the vendor file and i also use `AFNetowrking` in my podfile in cocoa pods. Removing the `AFNetworking` functionality in either is not an option. How do i go about solving this?

Comment: Have you tried removing it from the framework that uses AFNetworking, and seeing if it compiles/find the CocoaPods version of AFNetworking?

Comment: yes i have .. it doesn't

Comment: are you telling me to remove the vendor afnetworking file and compile the project to check if it finds the cocoapods version of the project?

Comment: Correct.  If it doesn't find it, then you'll have to add both (the framework and AFNetworking) to your project without CocoaPods, and modify the include paths in the framework to find your version of AFNetworking

Comment: Oh and which framework are you using that includes AFNetworking?

Comment: An internally made sdk to use the company resources

Comment: I had the same issue using afnetworking and stackmob pods the other day. Removing afnetworking fixed it because stackmob includes that whole lib. Do you have control over this internal sdk? You could just include all of afnetworking in it...

Comment: If it's an internal SDK that has AFNetworking, then just remove AFNetworking from CocoaPods and make sure your header paths point to the AFNetworking in the SDK - would that work?

Comment: Done. But still doesn't build successfully same error :(

Comment: @Quizically It means you have it also somewhere else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have these linked at the same time in the same project and *not* have duplicate symbols. The meaning of duplicate symbols is that the same symbols are being declared/imported multiple times which is exactly what is happening here. The only way to fix this is to remove the framework in one of the two locations. Even if it were possible to fix this you wouldn't want to since there's a possibility the versions of the same framework could diverge leaving you with different APIs based on which version you were working with which would be an amazingly confusing headache.

Comment: Keith, do you know, how to use AFNetworking in SDK project and in demo project for this SDK? If yes, I will create question.